# Youtube embed iFrame not appearing

Tags: html, css, iframe

Today I started coding a web page to demo our end of term graphics project and what I thought would be simple had ended up costing me a good couple hours of fiddling. Specifically, I have a youtube embed that isn't working. Here is the code for the page:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>3D OpenGL Chess Set</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner" class="banner">
<h1> Welcome to the home of our OpenGL chess set! </h1>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">

<div id="sidebar" class="menuBar">
<div id="ele1" class="menuElement"><a href="theTeam.html">The Team</a></div>
<div id="ele2" class="menuElement"><a href="theProject.html">The Project</a></div>
<div id="ele3" class="menuElement"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
<div id="ele4" class="menuElement"><a href="download.html">Download!</a></div>
</div>

<div id="mainContent" class="content">
<h1> Welcome, this is a webpage dedicated to our team's end of term project: a chess set designed using openGL and C++. </h1>
</div>

<div>
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QGRW7YJa4cg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the css looks something like this:

```
div.banner
{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content : center;

color:white;
font-size:large;

background-color:#606060;

height: 100px;
border: 10px groove black;
}

div.wrapper
{
height:1000px;

}

div.menuBar
{
color:white;
font-size:large;

float:left;

background-color:#606060;

width: 160px;
height: 1000px;
}

div.menuElement
{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content : center;

float:left;
color:white;
font-size:large;

width: 140px;
height: 180px;
border: 10px groove black;
}

div.content
{
display: flex;
justify-content : center;

color:Black;
}

p.center
{
font-size: xx-large;
text-align:center;
}
```

Fairly certain there is no problem with either, at least relevant to why iFrame isn't working, but better safe than sorry. I am completely stumped. So here's what happens, on my end at least. The web page loads pefectly except the player. That never loads, I end up with (using my page as an example) the header talking about the chess set them an empty content div below it. I don't even get the border of the player until I use the inspect elements option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
   Greg

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/wWu8J/

Comment: why are you using xml tag ?

Comment: Mostly an antiquated header that I really need to update, been copy + pasting that onto the top of my documents for as long as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `iframe` try to add "https" on `src` value, just like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QGRW7YJa4cg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Hey, this worked. Simple and sweet, thank you very much!